# Docker: created files disappear between layers

Tags: docker, dockerfile, mkdir

Running Docker version 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87, I have a dockerfile that looks like this:

```
FROM maven:3.5.2-jdk-8-alpine as builder

RUN chmod -R 777 /root/.m2 &&\
 mkdir -p /root/.m2/repository/com/foo/bar &&\
 echo "Text" > /root/.m2/repository/com/foo/bar/baz.txt &&\
 ls -R -a -l /root/.m2/repository/com/foo
RUN ls -R -a -l /root/.m2/repository/com/foo
```

The first RUN command successfully creates a file, but the second command can't find it:

```
Step 1/46 : FROM maven:3.5.2-jdk-8-alpine as builder
 ---> 293423a981a7
Step 2/46 : RUN chmod -R 777 /root/.m2 && mkdir -p /root/.m2/repository/com/foo/bar && echo "Text" > /root/.m2/repository/com/foo/bar/baz.txt && ls -R -a -l /root/.m2/repository/com/foo
 ---> Running in a1c0fd142856
/root/.m2/repository/com/foo:
total 12
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Nov 30 13:32 .
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Nov 30 13:32 ..
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Nov 30 13:32 bar

/root/.m2/repository/com/foo/bar:
total 12
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Nov 30 13:32 .
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Nov 30 13:32 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             5 Nov 30 13:32 baz.txt
 ---> b997ccbfd5b0
Step 3/46 : RUN ls -R -a -l /root/.m2/repository/com/foo
 ---> Running in 603671c87ecc
ls: /root/.m2/repository/com/foo: No such file or directory
The command '/bin/sh -c ls -R -a -l /root/.m2/repository/com/foo' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

What's going on?  (NB. this is a toy example, but there is a real issue in that JARs installed into the Maven repository seem to disappear between layers.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [upstream maven image](https://github.com/carlossg/docker-maven/blob/798decbb2f987a14f345c017f8fa3725c2467758/jdk-8-alpine/Dockerfile) defines this directory as a volume. Once an image does this, you cannot reliably make changes to that directory in the image.

From their Dockerfile:

```
ARG USER_HOME_DIR="/root"
...
VOLUME "$USER_HOME_DIR/.m2"
```

The [Dockerfile documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume) describes this behavior:

> Changing the volume from within the Dockerfile: If any build steps change the data within the volume after it has been declared, those changes will be discarded.

Your options are to:

- Use another directory for your build
- Request that the upstream image removes this `VOLUME` definition
- Build your own image without this definition (it's fairly easy to fork their repo and do your own build)

For more details, you can see an old [blog post](https://boxboat.com/2017/01/23/volumes-and-dockerfiles-dont-mix/) by me about this behavior and the problems it creates.